# UITextView inside UITableViewCell Keyboard Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textview, keyboard

As new to IOS development, I’ve been struggling with the problem of keyboard movement for several days. I embedded UISrollView which has UITableView with fixed height constraint inside UIViewController. Also I've created custom cells with unscrollable UITextView inside. The problem is that the keyboard doesn't move down when I type inside TextView.

I followed guidance from here: [Embedding UITextView inside UITableViewCell](https://medium.com/@georgetsifrikas/embedding-uitextview-inside-uitableviewcell-9a28794daf01) , but there is an example only with UITableView, not UIScrollView -> UITableView

Hope you understand my problem. Thanks in advance

Some additional Images/GIFs are attached below:

[My UIView hierarchy structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsXsk.png)

[Expected Behaviour of keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFUks.gif)

[Current behaviour of UIKeyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bgzb.gif)

View Controller code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Constraints
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()
        registerCell()
    }
}

//MARK: - Extensions

extension ViewController {

    func setupUI() {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    func registerCell() {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.reuseId)
    }

    func setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()
    {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))

        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard()
    {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.textChanged {[weak tableView] (_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                tableView?.beginUpdates()
                tableView?.endUpdates()
                self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
            }            
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Custom cell code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var textChanged: ((String) -> Void)?

    static let reuseId = "TableViewCell"

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textChanged(action: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        self.textChanged = action
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textChanged?(textView.text)
    }    
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that the keyboard isn’t moving down, but that the scroll view ain’t moving up.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is right, the current function you're experiencing is because you are adding new text in the middle of the scroll view rather than at the bottom of the scroll view.

If you want to make sure that the content you're editing is constantly above the keyboard then you'll have to calculate where the content ends and keyboard begins and move your views accordingly.

Here's some additional [info](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) that may help with keyboard issues.